# Jade Template in Meteor - Conditional Comparison Syntax Error

Tags: meteor, conditional-statements, pug

Trying to compare two template variables is resulting in an error. This seems consistent with jade syntax. What's wrong here?

Code:

```
if name == current_project.name
    | Current
else
    a.nav-project-selection Set as Current
```

Error:

```
   While building the application:
   client/templates/account.jade: Jade syntax error: Expected identifier, number, string, boolean, or null
   {{#if name == current_project.na...
   ^
```

Comment: You can't do variable comparisons in a spacebars `{{#if ...}}`

Comment: Does that mean you can't do it in Jade either?

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED**

Since Jade compiles down to Spacebars which doesn't support comparison, you have to do it via a helper function. The following worked for me:

client.js

```
UI.registerHelper('equals', function(a, b) {
    return (a === b);
});
```

template

```
if equals name current_project.name
    | Current
else
    a.nav-project-selection Set as Current
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use the [Meteor-handlebar-helpers](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers) package.

```
meteor add raix:handlebar-helpers
```

Check the readme file to get an overview of the helpers. In your case:

```
if $eq name current_project.name
  | Current
```